# Overflow-x : scroll not working

Tags: html, css

I have a div with floating (left) images inside, but the `overflow-x : scroll;` appears to not work..

this is my container :

```
.browse-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border-top: 7px solid #585453;
    background: #585453;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}
```

and the images :

```
.browse-gallery img {
    width: 109px;
    height: 81px;
    display: block;
    border-top: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 5.7px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

How can I solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle

Comment: using `float` takes things out of the flow of the document

Comment: So should I remove float ?

Comment: Yup,  remove the float

Comment: If you remove `float: left;` you'll also have to remove `display: block;`

Comment: @mehdi : you need to add `display:inline-block` instead `display:block`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove float and add display:inline-block: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9CuCH/)**

```
.browse-gallery img {
        width: 109px;
        height: 81px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: none;
        /*float: left;*/
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 5.7px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background:#fff;
    }
```

Comment: display:inline-block fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Delice you can give an upvote to this answer then ;)